# How to add a page link without remove previous pages link

Tags: javascript, php

I hope my question would not be let you guys misunderstand.
What I'm doing is, I have a `thank-you.php` now.

First, the user will be go to `www.jj.com/contact.php`.

My submit form will be showing `www.jj.com/thank-you.php` after the user submitted the form.

But now I want to combine the two pages into one url. Example: `www.jj.com/contact.php/thank-you.php`

`contact.php` & `thank-you.php` are in the same directory.

Any idea how I can change the URL like that?

Comment: use .htaccess and mod-rewrite

Comment: what does your 'combine' mean? do you just want to show the url like this or you want to make changes in screen also?

Comment: @RohitSharma Yes. I just want to show the URL like that.

Comment: `/contact.php/thank-you.php` does not make the most sense as a desired URL to begin with. Without any extra interference (rewriting), on a normally configured server, it would realize that `contact.php` is an existing script file, and just call that - the rest of the URL path would be passed on to that script as PATH_INFO. If you want “nicer” URLs, then you should perhaps start by eliminating the `.php` suffix - because what actual technology you are using, is of rather less interest to a human user.

Answer (score 3):

In the php file where the contact info is posted to, just use:

```
header('location: /contact/thank-you');
```

The above assume that the thank-you file is in actually in the contact directory. If not, you'll need to move it there.

Comment: Sounds like it is NOT in the contact dir but he wants to show it as if it was. That would be an htaccess change

Comment: Yeah, but using .htaccess to solve that problem could lead to problems later unless things are very well documented. Best to just have a good directory structure.

Comment: Sure.. I just wanted to point out my interpretation of the question

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new dir (`/contact`) and put your `thank-you.php` in this directory

**or**

you can rewrite in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact\.php/thank-you\.php/?$ thank-you.php [NC,L]
```